# Full-Text Searching with WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to use Full-Text Searching with WCF Data Services using Entity Framework as the backing source?

My current approach is to have a separate WCF Web Service method that preforms the full text search and returns the list of keys and then match on that, but this means the data must be retrieved from the WCF Service and then uploaded back up to the server to match keys.

Is there any better way to do this?

I have looked at: http://manfred-ramoser.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/full-text-search-for-entity-framework.html but it doesn't seem like this will work in a WCF Data Service environment.

Comment: @AdrianIftode care to try that again? please this time with making sense.

Comment: Sorry, in that article the author has noticed his search feature is a "pseudo" full text search, the generated sql statements will still use the LIKE operator

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link to implement full text search in WCF:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538